# Let $\{X_n; n\geq 0\}$ be a martingale with respect to $\{Y_n\}$. Prove for any set of integers $k\leq l<m$ that

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\{X_n; n\geq 0\}$ be a martingale with respect to $\{Y_n\}$. Prove for any set of integers $k\leq l<m$ that the difference $X_m-X_l$ is uncorrelated with $X_k$, that is, $$E[(X_m-X_l)X_k]=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

$X_n$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_n)$-martingale:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_k(X_m-X_l)]=\mathbb{E}[X_k\mathbb{E}[(X_m-X_l)|\mathcal{F}_k]]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[X_k(X_k-X_k)]=0$$

Comment: one hint is given to us **Evaluate the expectation by conditioning on $Y_1, Y_2......Y_k.$**

Comment: Usually filtration is denoted by $\mathcal{F}$ e.g. the natural filtration is $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$...

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more

Comment: Basically, you can do the same by conditioning on $Y_1,\dots,Y_k$. It means that you condition on the sigma algebra generated by those random variables.